# Cannot read property 'orderBy' of undefined

Tags: node.js, lodash, nestjs

I want to sort an array by the length of **adViews**.

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderBy' of undefined

How do I fix it?

```
  import _ from 'lodash';

  async maxViewsQuery(page = 1, relations = []): Promise<PaginatedResult> {
    const take = 14;
    const [data, total] = await this.adRepository.findAndCount({
      where: `("Ad__adViews"."id" IS NOT NULL)`,
      take,
      skip: (page - 1) * take,
      relations,
    });

    const sort = _.orderBy(data, (view) => view.adViews.length);

    return {
      data: sort.map((ad: Ad) => ({
        id: ad.id,
        title: ad.title,
        adViews: ad.adViews.length,
      })),
      meta: {
        total,
        page,
        lastPage: Math.ceil(total / take),
      },
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash doesn't use a default export, from the looks of it. Use

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

it seems your lodash module is not imported.
try importing only the function you require

`import { orderBy } from 'lodash';`